# Win 7x64, Sublime Text 3 & Babel => не транспайлит в ES5

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-3, babel

Проблему я собственно описал в заголовке. Посмотрел кучу видео, делаю все как там, почитал официальную документацию, насколько смог её понять естественно, сторонние источники тоже почитал. Не получается - хоть убей. Ошибок никаких нет. По разному пробовал - и babel-node, и core использовал. И просто cli. Все отрабатывает, но почему то на официальном сайте Babel переводит ES6 в ES5, а у меня, зараза, не хочет. Помогите пожалуйста советом.

На скрине результат, одинаковый во всех случаях
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp1D4.jpg

**Один из примеров**

Нода, npm и редактор, уже стояли, поэтому начну с установки Babel.
Итак.. Package Control => плагин Babel (+синтаксис JSX). Установил.
Настройки по умолчанию. Далее `npm init` в папке проекта. Конфиг package.json
`{
  "name": "sublimeTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist --presets env",
    "watch": "babel src -d dist --presets env -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}`
Установка Babel => `npm install --D babel babel-cli babel-core babel-node babel-preset-env`
Установил то же на всякий пожарный глобально.

далее создал файл **test.js** в папке **src**
далее в консоли `npm run build` и в папке **dist** создается файл **test.js**, но без изменений. Хотя по гайду, что я взял в пример, все работало. Как так-то?

**Второй пример**
Чтобы долго не писать, полностью повторил официальный гайд
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli/
результат тот же

**Сам спросил - сам ответил))**
В общем нашел в чем была проблема - конфликт версий. Между 6 и 7. Структура 7-ой версии модуля была переписана. А конфликт не сопровождается логом. Никакой сигнализации - вообще. Итак, перед тем как поставить\обновить, **не забудьте удалить предыдущую версию Babel.** Снес поставил заново Node, npm и новые версии модулей. Теперь все работает.

Comment: Вы хоть расскажите, что конкретно и как вы делаете, а то непонятно ничего. Кто отрабатывает? Где отрабатывает? Конкретные команды и конфиги в студию

Comment: @andreymal, я все понимаю. Простите пожалуйста, что так мало информации предоставил. Но если я начал бы подробно описывать всё то, что я делал, тема создавалась бы пару дней. Сейчас постараюсь вкратце, хотя один из примеров описать в вопросе

Comment: @andreymal, дополнил тему

Comment: Нашел в чем была проблема. Смотрим дополнение к теме.